# Orbeon Checkbox issue with pdf template

Tags: pdf, checkbox, orbeon

After following instructions from orbeons wiki

From: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-PDF-template-for-use-wit

*"Non-exclusive checkboxes
    Use PDF checkboxes
    Use the same name for all buttons
    Use different export values for each button
    The checkbox value (and NOT label) is used by Form Runner to match on the export value"*

we have not been able to allow checkboxes to a pdf template. It will allow one value to be passed. When you select more then one value in the Orbeon Runner the pdf doesn't show any values checked.

here is a sample form i built with an attached pdf:
http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/fr/testCheckBox/checkbox/new

Thanks!

Comment: @landyg, I am puzzled: I'd swear this used to work, but now I don't even seem to be able to create non-exclusive checkboxes in Acrobat, independently of Orbeon Forms. Could it be that you need the checkboxes to have different names? I asked the question here: http://goo.gl/Ikavi.

Comment: @avernet, I answered your question from http://goo.gl/Ikavi, but this still does not interact with orbeon. Please take a look.

Comment: @landyg, from what I gathered in that thread, we need to have different names for the checkboxes if we want to be able to select multiple checkboxes. So we can not have a checkbox `s$c` with value `1` and another one `s$c` with value `2`. Instead, I think we'll need the checkboxes to have names like `s$c$1` and `s$c$2`, both with a value `true`. I'll look into implementing this. If simple enough, I may just put the code in; otherwise, I'll open a bug, and update you here.

Comment: @landyg, checkboxes are now supported. You need to follow the convention mentioned in my previous comment for this to work. I can't tell you to get a nightly build to try this out yet, as we have another bug related to some changes we did recently in the persistence layer that prevents the PDF generation from working. We are fixing this other bug right now, and I'll post a follow-up when done. In the meantime, you can find the updated doc with the new syntax on: http://goo.gl/2i7NE.

Comment: @landyg, here we go: this is now taken care of, and I posted an answer below. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: @avernet thanks so much! we'll test and report back if any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with filling out checkboxes in PDF templates is fixed with the [nightly builds](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download) starting on 2011-05-13. If you have an existing template, you need to update the name of the checkboxes fields, as described in [How PDF templates work](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide#TOC-How-PDF-templates-work), and reattach the PDF to the form in Form Builder.